# Does kafka connector only support append only stream

Tags: apache-flink

I have following simple code snippet that want to write the streamin `group by` result into a kafka topic.

The Kafka sink table definition:

```
              CREATE TABLE sinkTable (
                id STRING,
                total_price DOUBLE
              ) WITH (
                'connector' = 'kafka',
                'topic' = 'test6',
                'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
                'key.format' = 'json',
                'key.json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true',
                'key.fields' = 'id',
                'value.format' = 'json',
                'value.json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',
                'value.fields-include' = 'ALL'
              )
```

When I run the following query

```
     insert into sinkTable
      select id, sum(price)
      from sourceTable
      group by id
```

it throws exception, the exception is:

```
Table sink 'default_catalog.default_database.sinkTable' doesn't support consuming update changes which is produced by node GroupAggregate(groupBy=[id], select=[id, SUM(price) AS EXPR$1])
```

I don't know where the problem is. I looks to me that `connector:kafka` doesn't support `group by` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is exactly as You've described it, the default `kafka` connector only supports append only stream. And as You may imagine the query You are trying to run, will produce an update for every new element, since it will change the sum for elements with this id.

One of the simplest things to do is to use `upsert-kafka` connector, which will automatically handle updates and write them to kafka, but this one is only available since Flink 1.12, so You may want to update Yourself to this version if You haven't yet.